# What is the difference between Load Balancer cookies stickiness and ElastiCache for storing user session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I have heard about two approaches to store user session in Amazon AWS. One approach is to use cookies stickiness with Load Balancer and the other is to store user session to ElastiCache. What are the advantages and disadvantages if I want to use the EC2 Load Balancer as well as ElastiCache? Where should I store the user session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS LB stickiness is something else, you can not store thing in LB stickiness, this is controlled by AWS underlying service. The load balancer uses a special cookie to track the instance for each request to each listener. When the load balancer receives a request, it first checks to see if this cookie is present in the request. If so, the request is sent to the instance specified in the cookie. If there is no cookie, the load balancer chooses an instance based on the existing load balancing algorithm.

> you can use the sticky session feature (also known as session
>   affinity), which enables the load balancer to bind a user's session to
>   a specific instance. This ensures that all requests from the user
>   during the session are sent to the same instance.

LB sticky sessions just route the subsequent request same ec2 instance from the same user, it will help application like WebSocket.

[lb-sticky-sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html)

[image]

So if you are looking for a way to management and store sensitive data and that data should be available across multiple nodes then you need 
[Distributed Session Management](https://aws.amazon.com/caching/session-management/) using Redis or Memcached. if you use case is just to stick the subsequent request to the same EC2 instance then LB stickiness is enough.

> There are many ways of managing user sessions in web applications,
>   ranging from cookies-only to distributed key/value databases,
>   including server-local caching. Storing session data in the web server
>   responding to a given request may seem convenient, as accessing the
>   data incurs no network latency. The main drawback is that requests
>   have to be routed carefully so that each user interacts with one
>   server and one server only. Another drawback is that once a server
>   goes down, all the session data is gone as well. A distributed,
>   in-memory key/value database can solve both issues by paying the small
>   price of a tiny network latency. Storing all the session data in
>   cookies is good enough most of the time; if you plan to store
>   sensitive data, then using server-side sessions is preferable.

[building-fast-session-caching-with-amazon-elasticache-for-redis](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/building-fast-session-caching-with-amazon-elasticache-for-redis/)

[image]